# OPencl returned zeros in the buffer

Tags: kernel, opencl, mql5, metatrader5

This is my kernel:

```
 const string cl_src = 
//" #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable                       \r\n"
"__kernel void CalculateSimpleMA(                                     \r\n"
                                 "int rates_total,                     \r\n"
                                 "int prev_calculated,                \r\n"
                                 "int begin,                          \r\n"
                                 "int InpMAPeriod,                    \r\n"
                                 "__global float *price,              \r\n"
                                 "__global float *storeValue          \r\n"
                                 ")                                    \r\n"
         "{                                                           \r\n"
            " int i,limit;                                               \r\n"
         " if(prev_calculated==0)// first calculation                 \r\n"
         "{                                                           \r\n" 
            "limit=InpMAPeriod+begin;                                 \r\n"
            "for(i=0;i<limit-1;i++) storeValue[i]=0.0;                \r\n"
            "double firstValue=0;                                     \r\n"
            "for(i=begin;i<limit;i++) firstValue+=price[i];           \r\n"
            "firstValue/=InpMAPeriod;                                 \r\n"
            "storeValue[limit-1]=firstValue;                          \r\n"
         "}                                                           \r\n"
         "else limit=prev_calculated-1;                               \r\n"
         "for(i= 0;i<rates_total;i++)                              \r\n"
            "storeValue[i]=storeValue[i-1]+(price[i]-price[i-InpMAPeriod])/InpMAPeriod;\r\n"

         "}                                                           \r\n";
```

The following is my OnCalculation():

```
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const int begin,
                const double &price[])
  {
//--- check for bars count
   if(rates_total<InpMAPeriod-1+begin)
      return(0);// not enough bars for calculation
//--- first calculation or number of bars was changed
   if(prev_calculated==0)
      ArrayInitialize(ExtLineBuffer,0);
//--- sets first bar from what index will be draw
   PlotIndexSetInteger(0,PLOT_DRAW_BEGIN,InpMAPeriod-1+begin);


 string str;   
int cl_ctx = CLContextCreate(CL_USE_GPU_ONLY);
   int cl_prg=CLProgramCreate(cl_ctx,cl_src,str);
   int cl_krn=CLKernelCreate(cl_prg,"CalculateSimpleMA");
   int cl_mem=CLBufferCreate(cl_ctx,ArraySize(price)*sizeof(float ),CL_MEM_READ_WRITE), 
       cl_price=CLBufferCreate(cl_ctx,ArraySize(price)*sizeof(float ),CL_MEM_READ_WRITE);

   if(cl_ctx==INVALID_HANDLE)
     {
      Print("OpenCL not found: ", GetLastError() );
      return(0);

     }

   //if(CLGetInfoString(cl_ctx,CL_DEVICE_NAME,str)) 
   //   Print("OpenCL device name: ",str);
   if(cl_prg==INVALID_HANDLE)
     {
      CLContextFree(cl_ctx);

      Print("OpenCL program create failed: ", str);
      return(0);
     }
     if(cl_prg==ERR_INVALID_PARAMETER )
     {
      CLContextFree(cl_ctx);

      Print("OpenCL program create failed: ", str);
      return(0);
     }
     if(cl_prg==ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY )
     {
      CLContextFree(cl_ctx);

      Print("OpenCL program create failed: ", str);
      return(0);
     }
     if(cl_prg==ERR_OPENCL_PROGRAM_CREATE )
     {
      CLContextFree(cl_ctx);

      Print("OpenCL program create failed: ", str);
      return(0);
     }
           if(cl_krn==ERR_OPENCL_INVALID_HANDLE )
           {
               CLProgramFree(cl_prg);
               CLContextFree(cl_ctx);
               Print("OpenCL kernel create failed : ERR_OPENCL_INVALID_HANDLE");
               return(0);
           }
           if(cl_krn==ERR_INVALID_PARAMETER )
           {
               CLProgramFree(cl_prg);
               CLContextFree(cl_ctx);
               Print("OpenCL kernel create failed : ERR_INVALID_PARAMETER");
               return(0);
           }
           if(cl_krn==ERR_OPENCL_TOO_LONG_KERNEL_NAME  )
           {
               CLProgramFree(cl_prg);
               CLContextFree(cl_ctx);
               Print("OpenCL kernel create failed : ERR_OPENCL_TOO_LONG_KERNEL_NAME");
               return(0);
           }
           if(cl_krn==ERR_OPENCL_KERNEL_CREATE )
           {
               CLProgramFree(cl_prg);
               CLContextFree(cl_ctx);
               Print("OpenCL kernel create failed : ERR_OPENCL_KERNEL_CREATE");
               return(0);
           }

           if(cl_mem==INVALID_HANDLE)
           {
               CLKernelFree(cl_krn);
               CLProgramFree(cl_prg);
               CLContextFree(cl_ctx);
               Print("OpenCL buffer create failed: cl_mem INVALID_HANDLE");
               return(0);
           }
           if(cl_mem==ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY )
           {
               CLKernelFree(cl_krn);
               CLProgramFree(cl_prg);
               CLContextFree(cl_ctx);
               Print("OpenCL buffer create failed: cl_mem ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY ");
               return(0);
           }
           if(cl_mem==ERR_OPENCL_BUFFER_CREATE )
           {
               CLKernelFree(cl_krn);
               CLProgramFree(cl_prg);
               CLContextFree(cl_ctx);
               Print("OpenCL buffer create failed: cl_mem ERR_OPENCL_BUFFER_CREATE ");
               return(0);
           }

           if(cl_price==INVALID_HANDLE)
           {
               CLKernelFree(cl_krn);
               CLProgramFree(cl_prg);
               CLContextFree(cl_ctx);
               CLBufferFree(cl_mem);
               Print("OpenCL buffer create failed: cl_price ");
               return(0);
           }
           if(cl_price==ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY)
           {
               CLKernelFree(cl_krn);
               CLProgramFree(cl_prg);
               CLContextFree(cl_ctx);
               CLBufferFree(cl_mem);
               Print("OpenCL buffer create failed: cl_price ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY");
               return(0);
           }
           if(cl_price==ERR_OPENCL_BUFFER_CREATE)
           {
               CLKernelFree(cl_krn);
               CLProgramFree(cl_prg);
               CLContextFree(cl_ctx);
               CLBufferFree(cl_mem);
               Print("OpenCL buffer create failed: cl_price ERR_OPENCL_BUFFER_CREATE ");
               return(0);
           }
//--- calculation
int  offset[2]={0,0};
   int  work  [2]={512,512};
   //float test[];
   //        ArrayResize(test,ArraySize(price));
   //        ArrayCopy(test,price);
   //uint inpMAPeriod = InpMAPeriod;
   switch(InpMAMethod)
     {
      case MODE_EMA:  CalculateEMA(rates_total,prev_calculated,begin,price);        break;
      case MODE_LWMA: CalculateLWMA(rates_total,prev_calculated,begin,price);       break;
      case MODE_SMMA: CalculateSmoothedMA(rates_total,prev_calculated,begin,price);break;
      case MODE_SMA:  
           if(!CLBufferWrite(cl_price, price))
           Print("Could not copy Input buffer"); 
           else Print("Copied: ",cl_price);               
           if(!CLSetKernelArgMem(cl_krn,4,cl_price))
           Print("Input Bufer Not Set");
          //else Print("Input Buffer Set");
           if(!CLSetKernelArgMem(cl_krn,5,cl_mem))
           Print("Output Bufer Not Set");
           //else Print("Output Buffer Set");

           //else Print("Input Buffer Copied");
           if(!CLSetKernelArg(cl_krn,0,rates_total))
           Print("Could Not Set Arg 0");
           //else Print("Set Arg 0");
           if(!CLSetKernelArg(cl_krn,1,prev_calculated))
           Print("Could Not Set Arg 1");
           //else Print("Set Arg 1");
           if(!CLSetKernelArg(cl_krn,2,begin))
           Print("Could Not Set Arg2");
           //else Print("Set Arg 2");
           if(!CLSetKernelArg(cl_krn,3,InpMAPeriod))
           Print("Could Not Set Arg3: ",GetLastError());


           //else Print("Set Arg 3");
           //CLSetKernelArg(cl_krn,4,cl_price);

           if(!CLExecute(cl_krn,2,offset,work))
           Print("Kernel not executed",GetLastError());
           //else Print("Executing Now!");
           if(CLExecutionStatus(cl_krn) == 0) Print("Completed");
           if(CLExecutionStatus(cl_krn) == 1) Print("CL_RUNNING");
           if(CLExecutionStatus(cl_krn) == 2) Print("CL_SUBMITTED");
           if(CLExecutionStatus(cl_krn) == 3) Print("CL_QUEUED");
           if(CLExecutionStatus(cl_krn) == -1) Print("Error Occurred:", GetLastError());

           if(!CLBufferRead(cl_mem,ExtLineBuffer))
           Print("Buffer Copy Nothing: ", GetLastError());
           break;
     }
      CLBufferFree(cl_price);
            CLBufferFree(cl_mem);
            CLKernelFree(cl_krn);
            CLProgramFree(cl_prg);

            CLContextFree(cl_ctx);

    return(rates_total);
  }
```

The above is my ull code.

the line which giving issue is:

```
if(!CLSetKernelArg(cl_krn,3,inpMAPeriod))
           Print("Could Not Set Arg3: ",GetLastError());
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Could Not Set Arg3: 5108
```

Guys,please help me anyone.. There is nothing I have found in relation to my issue, please help me.

EDITED:
These are the lines:

```
"for(i= 0;i<rates_total;i++) \r\n"
```

"storeValue[i]=storeValue[i-1]+(price[i]-price[i-InpMAPeriod])/InpMAPeriod;\r\n"

When I uncomment the lines, the OpenCL not found or the context is not created becomes as issue. The error I am getting is:

```
OpenCL: GPU device 'GeForce GT 730' selected
CL_QUEUED
Buffer Copy Nothing: 0
```

Please tell me if there is issue with the ilnes I have mention and if there is how I can resolve it.

Comment: You don't check for errors some of `OpenCL` functions like `CLSetKernelArg`. Also you check for one specific error like `INVALID_HANDLE` but many of them can return different errors which you don't check, for example: `CLBufferCreate` can return 3 different errors, `CLKernelCreate` 4 different errors and so on. Fixing that first should help you to narrow down where the problem really is.

Comment: Let me give it a try. I will update with the narrowed problem

Comment: But the creation points are not troubling the execution part is troubling. Check my updated approach.

Comment: @doqtor Getting the error as: `Kernel not executed:5109`

Comment: To verify if the kernel is the problem remove the content of the kernel and check if execution still fails on empty kernel. If it fails then the problem is before the kernel execution and you should do what I suggested in my first comment.

Comment: @doqtor I have tried the way you have said. I am now getting different error. Let me edit the question and you will see.

Comment: @doqtor Now please check the edited question. I am now getting the argument setting errors.

Comment: I guess the statement which passing `price` array from the `OnCalculation()` is the culprit. When I remove that statement and modified my kernel, the output started Queuing whereas with the statement active, nothing worked and got `5100` error code in the `GetLastError()`

Answer (score 1):

`CLSetKernelArgMemLocal` cannot be used to pass data from the host to the device. So the below statement is wrong: `CLSetKernelArgMemLocal(cl_krn,4,cl_price)`. `CLSetKernelArgMemLocal` can be only used to set the size for local buffer to be used inside the kernel. See the [manual](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/opencl/clsetkernelargmemlocal).

> local_mem_size [in]  Buffer size in bytes.

If you want to pass data from the host to the device it has to be either by value (`CLSetKernelArg`) or by global memory buffer (`CLSetKernelArgMem`).

I'm not familiar with mql5. I suspect the code should look like this:

```
CLBufferWrite(cl_price, price); // pass data to buffer
CLSetKernelArgMem(cl_krn,4,cl_price);
```

And the kernel parameter should change to: `__global float *price`.

Comment: ok but can you please show that in my code. That will help me improve. I guess I am missing something can you help?

Comment: Ihave already tried what you have suggested. I got error. When I commented the lines in kernel, the kernel went in Queued. These are the lines:`"for(i= 0;i<rates_total;i++)                              \r\n"
            "storeValue[i]=storeValue[i-1]+(price[i]-price[i-InpMAPeriod])/InpMAPeriod;\r\n"`  When I uncomment the lines, the OpenCL not found or the context is not created becomes as issue. Please tell me if there is issue with the ilnes I have mention and if there is how I can resolve it. I will upvote your answer as it partly helped me.

Comment: It would be good if you could update your question with the current state of the code. Also in the meantime make sure index `i` isn't out of range.

Comment: I have updated the question. I would like to know how I can check whether I is out of range or not, because even the print statement doesn't work in the kernel I have tried it previously.

Comment: What I meant was to put the current host and kernel code. As far as I remember print is not working on NVidia, so you can either write c++ code simulating this behaviour or do calculations in your head.

Comment: Yes I did that.. and I think there is no out of range issue as far as I know and updated the kernel code too

Comment: But your kernel and host code is still wrong - you still use that local buffer parameter and so on.

Comment: Opps.. Please pardon me.. now I have made the edits.. I guess I forgot to replace the code :P. PLease check it now.

Comment: storeValue[i-1] for i=0 is out of range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169498/discussion-between-jaffer-wilson-and-doqtor).